# Unknown column in where clause in C# app

Tags: c#, mysql

I am trying to develop C# app where I want to have login form connected to remote server. I connected to the server but when I try to login, the line :  MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(); is giving me an error: Unknown column "admin" in `where clause` Do you have any idea from where can come the problem? Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

namespace ECBSRecruitmentAgencySoftware
{
    public partial class LogIn : Form
    {
        public LogIn()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }  

        public bool tryLogin(string username , string password)
        {
             MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("host=aaaaaaaa.baaadsg;user=saaaaaak;password=2333333336;database=soaaaaaaaa2;");
             MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * FROM niki WHERE user_name = `" + username + "` AND user_password = `" + password + "`;");
             cmd.Connection = con;
             con.Open();
             MySqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
             if (reader.Read() != false)
             {
                 if (reader.IsDBNull(0) == true)
                 {
                     cmd.Connection.Close();
                     reader.Dispose();
                     cmd.Dispose();
                     return false;
                 }
                 else
                 {
                     cmd.Connection.Close();
                     reader.Dispose();
                     cmd.Dispose();
                     return true;
                  }
             }
             else 
             {
                 return false;
             }
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (tryLogin(user.Text, pass.Text) == true)
            {
                MainScreen F2 = new MainScreen();
                F2.Show();
                this.Hide();
            }            
            else 
                MessageBox.Show("Wrong details!");             
        } 
    }
 }
```

Comment: 1. You should use parameterized queries, not string concatenation.  You're very vulnerable to SQL injection.  2. You should not store plaintext passwords, you should store hashes of passwords and whenever someone enters a password you should immediately hash it and then disregard the plaintext password and just compare the two hashes.  3. rather than returning all columns from your query you should return count(*).  You only care *if* there is a row with the right user/pass, not what all of the info is.

Comment: I'm assuming you're trying to log in with the username of "admin" ?

Comment: @Servy can you give me example or somewhere from where I can look

Comment: try `' or '1'='1` in your textbox for password ;)

Comment: @Tremmors I replace the real username but lets pretend that this is the real one and yes I want to use that one.

Comment: Just wanted to make sure that was the username you meant and not the password or something else.

Comment: dont use backticks for values. use quotes

Comment: @NikolayDyankov I would start out googling "C# parameterized queries" "SQL injection" (that one's just for fun) and "C# hash password" and take a look at the results.  Look around; there's a lot of information on all of these topics.  If there is something in particular that you aren't getting it might be worth opening another topic on the subject rather than derailing this one.  I just wanted you to know that there is a problem so that you can start solving it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your query quote string using `'` instead of  ( ` )

```
Select * FROM niki WHERE user_name = '" + username + "' AND user_password = '" + password + "'
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * FROM niki WHERE user_name = '" + username + "' AND user_password = '" + password + "'");
```

The ` is to refer to table and columns names if the name is a reserved name. E.g. tbl.`from` will refer to a column called "from" and not the SQL reserved word FROM.

That ` is the reason you are getting an error message stating invalid column name "admin" as MySQL is thinking you are refering to a column called "admin" when it is finding `admin` in the command. No prizes of course for guessing you were entering "admin" as the username in your login form! :)

Answer (score 2):

Use named parameters instead of your solution:

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("Select * FROM niki WHERE user_name = @username AND user_password = @password");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", password);
```

UPD: updated to AddWithValue as UnhandledException said

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username)`?